# How can I see if the endIcon in a TextInputLayout is checked?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

There is an isEndIconChecked() in the EndCompoundLayout but I cannot see any access method to it from the TextInputLayout.

Whats the best way to detect if it is currently checked or not?

In my case I want a "Repeat password" input only be visible when the "password_toggle" end mode is not checked.

I looked into the source code and are now using as a workaround:

```
    binding.loginPassword.setEndIconOnClickListener {
        binding.loginPassword.editText?.apply {
            transformationMethod =
                if (transformationMethod is PasswordTransformationMethod) null
                else PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()
            binding.repeatPassword.isVisible = transformationMethod != null
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want to hide or show the password correct?

Comment: I want the normal behavior of the TextInputLayout that is set by app:endIconMode="password_toggle".

But additionally I want to toggle visibility of a repeat password field depending on the "password_toggle" state
So user does not have to repeat his password if he decides to enter it without character obfuscation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Combined with answer from Vsevolod, I am now using this helper functions:

```
@SuppressLint("DiscouragedApi", "ClickableViewAccessibility")
private fun registerPasswordCheck(view: TextInputLayout, update: () -> Unit) {
    val endIconViewId = resources.getIdentifier(
        "text_input_end_icon",
        "id",
        requireActivity().packageName
    )
    passwordShownCheck = view.findViewById(endIconViewId)
    passwordShownCheck.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
        if (event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) update()
        false
    }
}

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private fun isPasswordShownChecked() = passwordShownCheck.isChecked

private lateinit var passwordShownCheck: CheckableImageButton
```

Can be called with something like:

```
registerPasswordCheck(binding.newPassword) {
    binding.repeatPassword.isVisible = !isPasswordShownChecked()
}
```

This way the only internal from the API that is needed is the text_input_end_icon resource and the normal behavior of the password toggle does not have to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

`endIcon.isChecked` gives warning that "can only be called from within the same library group". But it works anyway.

```kotlin
val endIconViewId = resources.getIdentifier(
    "text_input_end_icon", 
    "id", 
    requireActivity().packageName
)
val endIcon: CheckableImageButton = binding.textInputLayout
    .findViewById(endIconViewId)
var showClearTextPasswordIsChecked = endIcon.isChecked
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add passowrd toggle in textInput you can try this

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/LogEmail"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.028"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                android:hint=" ">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/LogPass"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_background"
                    android:hint="Password..."
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/f"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).